# Require is not define after build run on another computer

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder, electron-forge

I have an electron application that I've made for a presentation. It's running great on my pc and I make a build of the application as an exe file so it can run on other computers, build runs fine on my pc but when I try to run the exact same build on another pc it gives an error on the console saying: "require" is not defined.

it's the same error when you turn context isolation is true. but it's false on my project. how can I fix it, Any ideas? I can provide details about the error if this is not sufficient.

thanks for any help :)

Expected: running the app and not getting the error
Result: App gives error even though it's context isolation is false